# Android. Don't parse value from json if it is not valid

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I am using retrofit and json converter. I create POJO which contains some fields. One of these fields should be int, but if the server sends something else instead of int, I need to not parse these value. Is it possible do not parse the value from json if it is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `setExclusionStrategies` on the `GSON` builder, if you're using `GSON`.
Like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setExclusionStrategies(new MyExclusionStrategy())
    .create();
```

Now you just need to create your strategy:

```
public class MyExclusionStrategy implements ExclusionStrategy {

    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return (f.getDeclaringClass() == YourPOJO.class  && f.getName().equals("field_name") &&
                f.getDeclaredType() != Integer.class)
    }
}
```

All you need to do is replace `YourPOJO` with the name of the class, `field_name` with the name of the field in your POJO, and this should work. Might require some slight modification, I did not test it.